# PyQt5 how to make QTableView fill Qdialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

## Preface

Hello, babies, I some question about PyQt5.
I create a QTableView in QDialog, and I want to set the QTableView fill up the QDialog, and I don't know how to accomplish it.(PS: I haven't learned Pyqt5 for a long time. I used tkinter to implement UI interface. If there are errors in the code, please point out)
**To better show my question, I change the background of QDialog to white, you can see that there are some space between QTableView and the border of QDialog, and I want to delete these space.)**

## Pictures

[image]
After changed
[image]
Run in Windows system
[image]

```
import json
import time
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit, QTableView, QHeaderView, QAbstractItemView, QSizePolicy
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import pyqtSignal, QTimer, QPersistentModelIndex
import operator


class Delete_keyword(QtCore.QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, keywords_data, keyword_file_path):
        super(Delete_keyword, self).__init__()
        self.dialog = QDialog()
        self.dialog.setStyleSheet('QDialog{border: none; background-color: white;}')
        self.dialog.resize(800, 500)
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Delete some keyword')
        self.dialog.setFixedSize(self.dialog.size())
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.dialog.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.sorted_keywords_data = sorted(keywords_data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.stand_item_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(self.sorted_keywords_data), 2)
        self.table_view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.table_view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        #
        self.keyword_file_path = keyword_file_path
        #
        self.table_view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table_view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.delete_button = QPushButton("delete")
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_func)
        self.delete_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.withdraw_button = QPushButton("backup")
        self.withdraw_button.clicked.connect(self.withdraw_func)
        self.withdraw_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.save_button = QPushButton("save")
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_func)
        self.save_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.stand_item_model)
        # set a cache 
        self.item_cache = OrderedDict()
        # 
        self.withdraw_count = 0

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.stand_item_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Count'])
        for index_, temp_data in enumerate(self.sorted_keywords_data):
            for index__, value in enumerate(list(temp_data)):
                stand_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                self.stand_item_model.setItem(index_, index__, stand_item)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table_view, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.delete_button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.withdraw_button, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.save_button, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.dialog.exec_()

    def delete_func(self):
        actually_indexes = self.table_view.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        trace_indexes = [QPersistentModelIndex(index) for index in actually_indexes]
        self.withdraw_count = len(trace_indexes)
        if self.withdraw_count != 0:
            self.withdraw_button.setEnabled(True)
        for trace_index, actually_index in zip(trace_indexes, actually_indexes):
            print(trace_index.row())
            self.item_cache[actually_index.row()] = (
                    self.stand_item_model.data(self.stand_item_model.index(actually_index.row(), 0)),
                    self.stand_item_model.data(self.stand_item_model.index(actually_index.row(), 1))
                )
            self.stand_item_model.removeRow(trace_index.row())

    def withdraw_func(self):
        for row, values in self.item_cache.items():
            for column, value in enumerate(values):
                stand_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                self.stand_item_model.setItem(row, column, stand_item)
            self.table_view.selectRow(row)
        self.item_cache.clear()
        self.withdraw_button.setEnabled(False)

    def save_func(self):
        rows = self.stand_item_model.rowCount()
        after_purify_keyword = OrderedDict()
        for row in range(rows):
            key = self.stand_item_model.data(self.stand_item_model.index(row, 0))
            value = self.stand_item_model.data(self.stand_item_model.index(row, 1))
            after_purify_keyword[key] = value
        with open(self.keyword_file_path, 'w+', encoding='U8') as f:
            json.dump(after_purify_keyword, f, indent='\t', ensure_ascii=False
```

Comment: **keywords_data** is a json data like this `{'a': 3, 'b': 5}` **keyword_file_path** is a normal file path

Comment: What do you mean by "fill up the dialog?" Please add details to the question, not to comments. Also please remove any greetings and salutations, as they are unnecessary for the question (and would be probably removed anyway).

Comment: @musicamante I'm sorry I didn't point out my core problem the first time, now I've revised

Comment: `self.grid_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`. And be aware that you cannot access any UI element from threads outside the main one, since widgets are ***not*** thread safe, so your `run()` is potentially dangerous (it will probably make the program crash sooner or later). Move everything ui related outside of that thread, and use signals to access the widgets.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your answer. After I run it here, there will still be a little gap on the left and right sides. Regarding the issue of thread insecurity, after your suggestion, I will read the book about semaphores and make program changes.

Comment: Please provide an *actual* [mre], without any code that is not related to the UI.

Comment: @musicamante I found the problem, it is about the PC, Mac and Windows have different questions.